# Kafka jdbc sink connector to Postgres failing with "cross-database references are not implemented"

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

My setup is based on docker containers - 1 oracle db, kafka, kafka connect and postgres. I first use oracle CDC connector to feed kafka which works fine. Then I am trying to read that topic and feed it into Postgres.
When I start the connector I am getting:

> "trace": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:614)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:329)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.sql.SQLException: Exception chain:\norg.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cross-database references are not implemented: "ORCLCDB.C__MYUSER.EMP"\n  Position: 14\n\n\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:122)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:586)\n\t... 10 more\nCaused by: java.sql.SQLException: Exception chain:\norg.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cross-database references are not implemented: "ORCLCDB.C__MYUSER.EMP"\n  Position: 14\n\n\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.getAllMessagesException(JdbcSinkTask.java:150)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:102)\n\t... 11 more\n"

My config json looks like :

```
{
"name": "SimplePostgresSink",
"config":{
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
  "name": "SimplePostgresSink",
  "tasks.max":1,
  "topics": "ORCLCDB.C__MYUSER.EMP",
  "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
  "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
  "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
  "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
  "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers":"kafka:29092",
  "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postgres",
  "connection.user": "postgres",
  "connection.password": "postgres",
  "insert.mode": "upsert",
  "pk.mode": "record_value",
  "pk.fields": "I",
  "auto.create": "true",
  "auto.evolve": "true"
}
```

}

And the topic schema is:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "ConnectDefault",
  "namespace": "io.confluent.connect.avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "I",
      "type": {
        "type": "bytes",
        "scale": 0,
        "precision": 64,
        "connect.version": 1,
        "connect.parameters": {
          "scale": "0"
        },
        "connect.name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal",
        "logicalType": "decimal"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "NAME",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "table",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "scn",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "op_type",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "op_ts",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "current_ts",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "row_id",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "username",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I am interested in the columns I and Name

Comment: Please show what data is in the topic, and what you expect the output postgres data to be

Answer (score 2):

This can also be caused by the db name in your connection.url not matching the db name in your table.name.format. I recently experienced this and thought it might help others.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the log I saw the connector has problem creating a table with such name:

> [2022-01-07 23:56:11,737] INFO JdbcDbWriter Connected (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter)
> [2022-01-07 23:56:11,759] INFO Checking PostgreSql dialect for existence of TABLE "ORCLCDB"."C__MYUSER"."EMP" (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect)
> [2022-01-07 23:56:11,764] INFO Using PostgreSql dialect TABLE "ORCLCDB"."C__MYUSER"."EMP" absent (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect)
> [2022-01-07 23:56:11,764] INFO Creating table with sql: CREATE TABLE "ORCLCDB"."C__MYUSER"."EMP" (
> "I" DECIMAL NOT NULL,
> "NAME" TEXT NOT NULL,
> PRIMARY KEY("I","NAME")) (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.DbStructure)
> [2022-01-07 23:56:11,765] WARN Create failed, will attempt amend if table already exists (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.DbStructure)
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cross-database references are not implemented: "ORCLCDB.C__MYUSER.EMP"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Extending on [Steven's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72573922/12988011)

This can also occur if your topic name contains full stops

If your `table.name.format` it defaults to `${topicName}`